# How to create /etc/shadow hash values with openssl

Tags: openssl

`user1's` password is `HelloWorld`

```
root@kali:~# cat /etc/shadow | grep user1
user1:$6$GRZcztBQ$.eHNZsczu4D3g7bsGkZlVKi14nLG/5W8WXXr7vKbziwkKHCnq3fvBO.j1KPcVxyTqy/5.DXZy4lD8QqH1H2bH/:16458:0:99999:7:::

root@kali:~#
```

How can I produce the same hash digest for user1's password using openssl?

In my openssl command below, I don't get the same hash value as stored in `/etc/shadow` for user1. What am I doing wrong? I'm even using the same salt.

```
root@kali:~# echo -n $GRZcztBQ\$HelloWorld | openssl dgst -sha512
(stdin)= 0afd50eb46b2004be59c3ac2b53e456e5359dc20debe561afabafdaac0eda7d1e666b766de537bbc663f8b2290f2177fc16659e874c05ce5651f0722c65f901c

root@kali:~#
```

Comment: l left out an forward slash before the first '$' in my openssl command, but it made no difference. My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to create /etc/shadow hash values with openssl

From the Unix/Linux Stack Exchange: [Manually generate password for /etc/shadow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/81240/56041):

```
openssl passwd -1 -salt <salt> <your password>
```

The answers also provide additional methods in case you want to forgo OpenSSL.